# How to calculate image size on SpriteKit coordinate with ArKit 1.5?

Tags: sprite-kit, arkit

I was read this answer about Recognizing Images [at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176796/how-to-track-image-anchors-after-initial-detection-in-arkit-1-5). But I still don't understand this answer: "if you want to know the size/extent, you can get that from the physicalSize of the detected reference image".

I can create an SCNPlane from property 'physicalSize' on SceneKit like Apple sample, but it is the meter unit in real-world. The unit of SpriteKit coordinate is the pixel, so I can't use it on SpriteKit. When ArKit detects image object on SpriteKit, the properties 'calculateAccumulatedFrame' and 'frame' are zero, so I don't know image size on SpriteKit coordinate. I still don't know how to calculate image size on SpriteKit coordinate?

Sorry, my English is not good.

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: I did solved it. We need to calculate the distance between photo and camera.